# python version of openssl passwd

Tags: python, pyopenssl

> The openssl passwd command computes the hash of a password typed at run-time or the hash of each password in a list. The password list is taken from the named file for option -in file, from stdin for option -stdin, and from the command line otherwise. The UNIX standard algorithm crypt and the MD5-based BSD password algorithm 1 and its Apache variant apr1 are available.

https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/openssl_passwd.1.asp

Here is an example of a working commandline:

```
# openssl passwd -salt lol "input"
lokvI0eY9X.FM
```

Is there a python module that handles password generation with openssl? [The documentation doesn't appear to cover generating passwords.](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html)

Comment: For 3.6, secrets could be helpful: https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html

Comment: `cryptography` has lots of key generation algorithms: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/key-derivation-functions/ . `openssl`'s default algorithm, `crypt` is usually considered obsoleted.

Comment: anyone know which algorithm is used? trying to troubleshoot if the "unix standard algorithm crypt" is being used internally in `openssl passwd`. then if i knew which algo was used, i could more easily validate that the input + salt returned the right value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the same behavior like `openssl passwd`, which using unix standard crypt(3), python has a `crypt` module:

```
import crypt
crypt.crypt('input', salt='lol') # => 'lokvI0eY9X.FM'
```

Comment: As of Python 3.11, the crypt library is deprecated; you can use the passlib library for any functionality it has (including unix crypt behavior).