# MD5-based password algorithm in Python

Tags: python, openssl, md5, crypt, hashlib

I try to call API that specifically uses MD5 hash in one of the steps. In the documentation they specifically show example reference that generates MD5 in the following way

```
$ openssl passwd -1 -salt stack overflow
$1$stack$MVcBmQ3RlrBu5Xoj74NBA0
```

or to be more exact, they just use the part after the third `$`

```
$ openssl passwd -1 -salt stack overflow | cut -f 4 -d '$'
MVcBmQ3RlrBu5Xoj74NBA0
```

At first, I tried to use `hashlib` and got the hexadecimal output that does not resemble the exampla at all.

```
salt = b'stack'
input = b'overflow'
output = hashlib.md5(salt + input).hexdigest()
print(output)

73868cb1848a216984dca1b6b0ee37bc
```

I figured that I just need to decode those hex values to characters, but decode does not work for default `utf8` or for `latin1`

```
salt = b'stack'
input = b'overflow'
output = hashlib.md5(salt + input).digest().decode()
print(output)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x86 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

I found some help here [python version of openssl passwd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49442294/python-version-of-openssl-passwd) and here [MD5 hash in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416164/md5-hash-in-python)

I could reproduce this one with `crypt`

```
$ openssl passwd -salt stack overflow
st22n6QiCXNQY
```

```
salt = 'stack'
input = 'overflow'
output = crypt.crypt(input, salt)
print(output)

st22n6QiCXNQY
```

But as soon openssl passwd `-1` is added, which stands for

```
-1                  MD5-based password algorithm
```

I cannot reproduce it anymore.

How can I recreate MD5-based password algorithm in Python? I would preferably use `hashlib` if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux you can do this with the [crypt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html) module. However it will be removed in Python 3.13.

```
import crypt
crypt.crypt("overflow", "$1$stack")
```

Here $1$ specifies the use of MD5 and "stack" is the salt.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much! I would never figure this one out.
I also found the solution with the `passlib`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution using `passlib`

```
from passlib.hash import md5_crypt

salt = 'stack'
input = 'overflow'
output = md5_crypt.using(salt=salt).hash(input)
print(output)

$1$stack$MVcBmQ3RlrBu5Xoj74NBA0
```